Gurgle in Tub When Toilet Flushes
I recently had a clogged tub.  I was able to clear the clog enough by snaking the line right at the stack (where the compression fitting is).  After doing that, A gurgle in the tub developed when you flush the toilet. I assume there is a clog that I have pushed into the stack to affect the air flow, but now I am trying to find the best way to snake the stack.  My first that is to open up that drain pipe where the compression fitting is and use a bigger auger or even a hose with water?  There is a plug at the floor, but I am not sure how successful that would be going up.
I want to avoid going on the roof.
Any thoughts of how best to tackle this without calling a plumber.
.

In my case, this seems to be due to the vent stack being blocked (bird's nests or something similar). Haven't gotten up there to flush it out yet.

I think if my issue hadn't presented itself so soon after I cleared the clog, I would agree.  Probably a similar issue, but there is steep pitch to my roof and it would be harrowing to  do that climb without the right ladder.

Mine is also steep and high, and I will either arrange proper safety equipment, hire someone to deal with it, or try to figure out how to use poles and ropes and jigs to get the hose up there while remaining on a safer surface. Hiring someone is probably simplest and fastest.

IT's not likely that you would push a clog from a 2 inch pipe into a 3 inch pipe. Do you use the tub regularly?  If the P Trap under the tub is dry you will hear the flow of the water in the drain.  Put some water in the tub, open the drain and flush the toilet.  If there is a clog you will get a bubble from the tub drain.

The tub is used regularly being a 1 bath house, but when you run water in the tub and flush, there is no gurgle.  Curious if the P trap is deep enough, if that is possible?

It's a vent issue. Where the vent issue is is the harder question. Did you clean the main line only, or did you clean the  line to the tub only, or did you clean both directions when you had the fitting apart? Is there a vent line for the tub trap? It appears that the connection to the stack drops too much for it to be wet-vented correctly through that.
